# Error installing and using npm in laravel 8.12

Tags: laravel, breeze

how are you? I tell you a bit about my problem, I want to install laravel breeze and when I'm using the command `npm install && npm run dev`  I get this error, I also have node **v12.5.0** installed on my pc, I would appreciate your help.

[Image to error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfRdg.png)

Comment: The message pretty clearly asks you to update to v12.14, so I'd start there.

Answer (score 2):

You should have Node v12.14 at least. Update your node.